# how can i select data from datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

My `datatable` contain column "**Date**" that have data like this in the following

```
'2013-01-01',
'2013-05-01',
'2014-01-01',
'2014-12-25',
'2014-12-26
```

But i want to get data something like '`select distinct year(Date)`', and bind selected data into dropdownlist 
however, syntax error message popup: "`Syntax error: Missing operand after 'year' operator.`"
can I get any support? THANKS!!!!

```
private DataTable BuildDT(string [] date)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("test");

    dt.Columns.Add("RowID", typeof(Int16));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));        

    for (int i = 0; i < date.Length; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i+1,date[i]); // {1,2013-01-01}
    }
    return dt;
}


private void ddlGetData2(DataTable table)
{
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "distinct year(Date)";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ...

```
var years = table.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Year)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(y => y)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I took a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx and don't see any reference to distinct as a supported expression for RowFilter

Comment: if i replace '`table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "distinct year(Date)";`' by above lines error prompt "`Specified cast is not valid.`" can u help more? thx

Comment: Just noticed the Date column is meant to be a `DateTime` but it's being populated with `string`s. Do you want it to be `string`s or `DateTime`s?

Comment: i think it would be `datetime `

Comment: Instead of `dt.Rows.Add(i+1,date[i]);`, try converting it to a date before inserting to the data table... `dt.Rows.Add(i+1, DateTime.ParseExact(date[i], "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.ToTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the associated `DataView` instance.

```
var dv = dt.DefaultView;
var distinctDates = dv.ToTable(true, "Date");
```